# Can't run native base on web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I have [this](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink) native base template,
 I run it on android and IOS but i can't run it on web

how can i do this ?

when i do `npm start` 
it give me port 8081 and this result:

[image: this result]

```
> NativebaseKitchenSink@2.5.0 start /home/dina/Downloads/react native template/NativeBase-KitchenSink-master
> node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start

Scanning folders for symlinks in /home/dina/Downloads/react native template/NativeBase-KitchenSink-master/node_modules (10ms)
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Looking for JS files in
   /home/dina/Downloads/react native template/NativeBase-KitchenSink-master 


Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph...::1 - - [06/Jun/2018:07:12:00 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 150 "http://localhost:8081/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/66.0.3359.139 Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36"
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: my-app
  Paths: /home/dina/Downloads/react native template/NativeBase-KitchenSink-master/my-app/my-app/package.json collides with /home/dina/Downloads/react native template/NativeBase-KitchenSink-master/my-app/package.json

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
Loading dependency graph, done.
```

Comment: React Native is not meant to be run in webbrowsers. Maybe you can use something like this to make it happen: https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web

Comment: this native base template already has a react-native-web branch, maybe he isn't using it.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked this. Working for me. Try following these steps

1. `create-react-app myApp`.
2. run `yarn eject`.
3. copy the contents of `config/webpack.config.dev.js` and `package.json` of https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink branch `web-support`
4. do `yarn` or `npm install`.
5. update `native-base` to the latest version.(else you may face some errors)
6. Add some native-base components to `App.js`.
7. run `npm run start`. You can see the app getting rendered on the browser.

If you come across this issue https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1957 try renaming the folder for a temporary fix.

Comment: thanks for help but i can't find this file  webpack.config.dev.js

Comment: after running `yarn eject` a config folder will appear in the project root. You can see the `webpack.config.dev.js` file there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I made this dream using the "npx" command. This bug appears to occur from the "0.45.00" version of react-native.

To be able to start my project following the steps:

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app
$ cd my-app
$ npm start
```

Support material, with step-by-step used: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html